# How could Google Analytics and my report through Google Data Chart be giving me different numbers?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

So I am using googleCharts.DataChart to display analytics results from my site on my site.  Hovever it is showing all pages with the same number of pageviews.  If i click on one page all the other pages increase their pageviews.

if i run this query on my page

```
 query: {
      'dimensions': 'ga:eventLabel' ,
            'metrics' : 'ga:pageviews',
      'start-date': 'yesterday',
      'end-date': 'today',
            'filters': "ga:dimension1=="+userid,
    }, 
    chart: { 
      type: 'BAR',
      container: 'timeline',
            options: {
                title:'Page Views',
                height:'800',
                width: '500',
                hAxis: {
                 title:'Views',
                 minValue:0,
                 gridlines:{count:7}
                },
                vAxis:{title:'Page'} 
            }
    }
  });
```

everypage except 1 returns the same number of page views, but all pages are increasing with every page view I give tracked pages.

When go look at the report  for the same exact query on my analytics account the numbers dont match up with what is being shown in the DataChart.

Here is the whole Twig Template im using to run the Query

```
{#<!-- Step 1: Create the containing elements. -->#}
<section id="auth-button"></section>
<section id="view-selector-1"></section>
<section id="timeline"></section>


{#<!-- Step 2: Load the library. -->#}

<script>
(function(w,d,s,g,js,fjs){
  g=w.gapi||(w.gapi={});g.analytics={q:[],ready:function(cb){this.q.push(cb)}};
  js=d.createElement(s);fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  js.src='https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);js.onload=function(){g.load('analytics')};
}(window,document,'script'));
</script>

<script>
gapi.analytics.ready(function() {

  // Step 3: Authorize the user.
  var CLIENT_ID = myClientID;
    var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split('/');



  gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
    container: 'auth-button',
    clientid: CLIENT_ID,
  });

  // Step 4: Create the view selector.

  var viewSelector = new gapi.analytics.ViewSelector({
    container: 'view-selector-1'
  });

  // Step 5: Create the timeline chart.

    var view = document.getElementsByClassName('views-field-nid');


    var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split('/');
    var userid = pathArray[2];
        //console.log(pathArray[2]+' path array 1');
  var timeline = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({

    reportType: 'ga',
    query: {
      'dimensions': 'ga:eventLabel' ,
            'metrics' : 'ga:pageviews',
      'start-date': 'yesterday',
      'end-date': 'today',
            'filters': "ga:dimension1=="+userid,
    }, 
    chart: { 
      type: 'BAR',
      container: 'timeline',
            options: {
                title:'Page Views',
                height:'800',
                width: '500',
                hAxis: {
                 title:'Views',
                 minValue:0,
                 gridlines:{count:7}
                },
                vAxis:{title:'Page'} 
            }
    }
  });



  // Step 6: Hook up the components to work together.

  gapi.analytics.auth.on('success', function(response) {
    viewSelector.execute();
  });

  viewSelector.on('change', function(ids) {
    var newIds = {
      query: {
        ids: ids
      }
    }
    timeline.set(newIds).execute();
    //timeline2.set(newIds).execute();

  });

});
</script>
```

Comment: Not sure but it might be that the interface and the API work in different timezone settings. Try a larger timeframe (and one that does not include "today") to see if the results are closer together.

Comment: That must be it. I dont know what was going on but the clicks are closer